# Map json data to corresponding Class

Tags: java, json, apache-camel, gson, jms

I Have a JSON data in String format.This JSON data is coming from a JMS queue.
 ex:-

```
String msg=" {"id":"4","item":"GOT","description":"hello"}";
```

I am converting this JSON string to the Corresponding class object by using Gson library

```
Gson g = new Gson();   
BooksTable b1 = g.fromJson(msg, BooksTable.class); //BooksTable is a POJO class with getter setters
addBook(b1);   //used to insert object into the database Books table
```

Now the problem is that this json can either be of books table or of transaction table which has json of the format

```
String msg=" {"id":"2","name":"deposit","purpose":"savings"}";
```

I want to dynamically map objects to corresponding classes based on JSON string.

for example: if Books JSON comes send it to Books table if Transaction JSON comes send it to the Transaction table.

How can I do that? If apache camel can do this please tell how to approach?
Any approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind, disregard my answer, I just realized it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Can't you do a simple `if()else` based on where your message comes from? I take it you have something like `String msg = someDBHandler.doThings()`? If you can't do that, you might be able to simply scan your json for unique keys, but I don't recommend this. For example `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(msg); if(obj.has('purpose')) { // Do TransactionTable things } else if(obj.has('item')) { // Do BookTable things } `

Comment: yes, but the use case I referred is a simple use case. What if there are hundreds of table, with each table having multiple columns.Matching each column would not be efficient.

Comment: Well this is more difficult to approach, if you have an Object of basically type `?` returned, then how would you handle this later down the line? I could imagine something like `Object j = g.fromJson(msg, Class.forName('some.package.identifierFromMessageOrSomething'));` but it might not help much in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `camel-jsonpath` to check if the JSON String contains a certain field:

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <jsonpath suppressExceptions="true">$.item</jsonpath>
        <!-- Unmarshal to Book -->
    </when>
    <when>
        <jsonpath suppressExceptions="true">$.name</jsonpath>
        <!-- Unmarshal to Transaction -->
    </when>
</choice>
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by parsing the JSON using the [`JsonParser`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html), so you can examine it, then unmarshal to the appropriate object type using [`Gson`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.2/com/google/gson/Gson.html).

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        process("{\"id\":\"4\",\"item\":\"GOT\",\"description\":\"hello\"}");
        process("{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"deposit\",\"purpose\":\"savings\"}");
    }
    private static void process(String json) {
        JsonObject object = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
        if (object.has("item")) {
            Book book = new Gson().fromJson(object, Book.class);
            System.out.println(book);
        } else if (object.has("name")) {
            Transaction transaction = new Gson().fromJson(object, Transaction.class);
            System.out.println(transaction);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unknown JSON: " + json);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
class Book {
    private int id;
    private String item;
    private String description;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book[id=" + this.id +
                  ", item=" + this.item +
                  ", description=" + this.description + "]";
    }
}
```

```java
class Transaction {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String purpose;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Transaction[id=" + this.id +
                         ", name=" + this.name +
                         ", purpose=" + this.purpose + "]";
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Book[id=4, item=GOT, description=hello]
Transaction[id=2, name=deposit, purpose=savings]
```

Comment: This would work for a simple use case . Consider i have 3 tables with columns:- 
Table 1 - id , item ,name 
Table 2 - id,item, description
Table 3  - id , purpose, item
and many other tables with many similar columns

Comment: @ShubhamChopra I don't see your point. You asked for a way to write code to unmarshal to different object types depending on the JSON text only, with no other guiding information. This is the answer to that. If all you  have is the JSON text, figuring out the detection logic is up to you. If you have more information that just the JSON text, then your question should have said so, and you'd then base the detection on that (too).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check out this extension to camel -- [JSON Schema Validator Component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-json-validator/src/main/docs/json-validator-component.adoc). It should work the same as the original validator in camel, but it allows you to validate your message body against the schema.